# FTPS With Java Binding and client CA Certificate

Tags: java, curl, digital-certificate, ftps

I am struggling to find an FTPES ( Must be explicit ) FTPS with a Java Client API.  I have an FTPS server that needs a CA certificate as well as username and password.  Now I can do this with something like SmartFTp or Curl which allows me to have a client side certificate check.  I had a look at a Java binding for Curl - that could be an option but I'd rather use a direct API client library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the [edtFTPPro/J](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html) commercial library for SFTP/FTP, and it works really good. Also supports FTPS, and at least for SFTP, you can use your own certificates. Haven't used it for FTPS, but I'd expect it to work fine. They also have very good response times on their forums.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) supports explicit mode, and looks to support client authentication, although I have not used that functionality.

Also, check out the [KeyManagerUtils](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/net/util/KeyManagerUtils.html) and [TrustManagerUtils](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/net/util/TrustManagerUtils.html) as well, as it doesn't appear to read the javax.net.ssl.keyStore and javax.net.ssl.trustStore properties.